# TRYING TO FIND OUT IF A PATENT IS CURRENTLY VALID OR ACTIVE OR PAID ITS FEES

Tags: us20120324755, a1

HELLO I AM TRYING TO FIND OUT IF THIS PATENT IS UPDATED AND PAID ITS FEES OR ABANDONED.  CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME OUT WHERE WOULD I FIND OUT IF ITS OK OR NOT TO TRY TO PATENT SOMETHING LIKE THIS OR SIMILAR OR NO QUESTION YOU CANNOT PATENT ANYTHING SIMILAR TO THIS IDEA. US20120324755 A1

Comment: Can you, like, not use caps lock?

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, please understand that writing in all caps is the internet equivalent of shouting at the top of your lungs. It is hard to read and makes people think you are rude.  That said, if you look at [Google Patent's](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20120324755A1/en) view you see the application is listed as "Abandoned". The definitive check for US patents and applications is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. You need to get by a CAPTCHA and, select Publication Number and enter 20120324755. Here you will find all sorts of information about the application. The current status is indeed "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 02-04-2015. I don't know whether or not it is possible to recover the application, but I doubt this application will ever be granted as a patent.

As to your second question about patenting something similar, it is hard to definitively answer. You can't patent the same idea since this application is still considered prior art. It may be possible to patent something similar so long as there is some new inventive aspect. The cited application received a non-final rejection, so it would be very helpful for you to review the documents on the US Public Pair to see what the patent examiner communicated in the rejection. It could lead you to other relevant patents and prior art.

Comment: I'm trying to get info about US1731272-A from the link you provided. It says can't be found. I tried all sorts of formats as suggested in the error, none found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3474042 US1731272 is a patent from 1929. It expired 70 years ago. It turns out this patent is too old for PAIR. I'm not sure what you info you are seeking, but if it is important to you try posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Last Event were PG-Pub Issue Notification and Notice of Publication on December 27, 2012. So it's even not a patent, just pending application.

Comment: The application seems to be abandoned, not pending. See my answer.